# How to get Tumblr post URL from post ID

Tags: tumblr

Since the IDs of Tumblr posts are globally unique, I would expect there to be a way to get the full URL (someblog.tumblr.com/post/POST_ID) when all I have is POST_ID.  Is there indeed a way?

I would also like this to work for blogs using a custom domain.

Answer (score 1):

For blogs on tumblr.com, you should *probably* be able to use advanced [Google search parameters](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433). To wit:

```
site:tumblr.com inurl:{POST_ID}
```

My tests were inconclusive. Much of the time Google returned nothing, but other times it returned exactly one result.

---

Hmmm...it looks like maybe `inurl:` is deprecated. I had much better results with:

```
site:tumblr.com/post/{POST_ID}
```

For blogs with custom domains, you're probably limited to using `inurl:`.